# Array.count works fine locally but breaks on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord, count, heroku

Right now, if I go to the index action of a model that I have, I don't show the basic table of data that rails generates for me if there are no existing records in the database. I do something like:

```
<% if @my_records.count > 0 %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>...</th>
    <th>...</th>
    <th>...</th>
    <th>etc</th>
  </tr>
  <% @my_records.each do |my_record| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=h my_record.etc %></td>
    <td><%=h my_record.etc %></td>
    <td><%=h my_record.etc %></td>
    <td><%=h my_record.etc %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
<% end %>
```

This works locally. However, when I push my app to heroku, this causes a 500 error and the log says:
`ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method 'count' for []:Array) on line ...`

So I change it to `.length` and it works fine. Can anyone tell me why that is? Someone has told me that these were redundant and rails got rid of `.count` but my understanding was that `.length` is an `Array` function that tells you how many items are in the `Array` and `.count` was an `ActiveRecord` method for determining how many items in the array were actual records in the database.

Can anyone shed light on this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's ruby issue, not rails. Locally you probably have 1.8.7, and heroku has 1.8.6. The `Enumerable#count` method was introduced in 1.8.7: compare http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.6/classes/Enumerable.html and http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Enumerable.html.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply and you are right! It turns out that I can migrate my application (running on Heroku aspen) to Heroku Bamboo (which supports 1.8.7 and 1.9.1) See: http://docs.heroku.com/bamboo .